# Trying to display each row in csv file in a terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal

The csv file gets created when I scrape but it doesn't display in the terminal. I want to display each row onto the screen

```rb
def get_aspley_data
  url = "https://www.domain.com.au/rent/aspley-qld-4034/?price=0-900"

    unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(url)
  parsed_page    = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)

  house_listings = parsed_page.css('.listing-result__details')
  house_listings.each do |hl|
    prop_type      = hl.css('.listing-result__property-type')[0]
    price          = hl.css('.listing-result__price')[0]
    suburb_address = hl.css('span[itemprop=streetAddress]')[0]

    house_array = [house_listings]
    house_array.push("#{prop_type} #{price}")

      aspley_dis = CSV.open($aspley_file, "ab", {:col_sep => "|"}) do |csv|
      csv << [prop_type, price, suburb_address]
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below one

```
def get_aspley_data
  url = "https://www.domain.com.au/rent/aspley-qld-4034/?price=0-900"

  unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(url)
  parsed_page    = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
  house_listings_data = []
  house_listings = parsed_page.css('.listing-result__details')
  house_listings.each do |hl|
    prop_type      = hl.css('.listing-result__property-type')[0]
    price          = hl.css('.listing-result__price')[0]
    suburb_address = hl.css('span[itemprop=streetAddress]')[0]

    house_array = [house_listings]
    house_array.push("#{prop_type} #{price}")
    house_listings_data << [prop_type, price, suburb_address]
    puts [prop_type, price, suburb_address].to_csv(col_sep: "|")
  end
  File.open($aspley_file, "ab") do |f|
    data = house_listings_data.map{ |d| d.to_csv(col_sep: "|") }.join
    f.write(data)
  end
end
```